# I try to download a local file with a button but the file cannot be found

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add a button on my page so that when I click on it, it downloads a file on the web browser I use.
The file I want to download is on my project:

[image]

And the script for the button is as follows:

```
download(){
      const link = document.createElement("a")
      link.href = "../../public/Programme robot/programme_palettisation_robot.tb"
      link.setAttribute("download", "programme_palettisation_robot.tb")
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
      document.body.removeChild(link)
      setTimeout(function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href); },1500)
    }
```

The problem is that when I click on the button, it says that the file cannot be found.

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If that file is stored in `public`, why not use a proper link?

Comment: You could check what url it tries to use. Do not use relative path, it's unsuitable here.

Comment: The file is stored in `public` and I have tried using a link like that: `<a href="../../public/Programme robot/programme_palletisation_robot.tb" download>Télécharger</a>`

Comment: @EstusFlask how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using the Vue CLI. Vue is running a local server in dev mode, basically creating a structure similar to the one you can see in the `dist` folder. Your links `href` is not parsed by webpack at build time, which is why you are actually trying to load the file relative from root.

Using an absolute file path should therefore fix it.

```js
link.href = "/Programme robot/programme_palettisation_robot.tb"
```

Comment: I have just tried your solution but I still have my problem

Comment: Can check if the file is actually there by navigating to `http://localhost:WHATEVERYOURPORTIS/public/Programme robot/programme_palettisation_robot.tb` and see if it downloads it correctly?

Comment: I have this message showing : `vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:71 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/public/Programme%20robot/programme_palettisation_robot.tb"` 
I think I might have put my file in the wrong place but I don't understand why. On VSCode, I have my file in my `public` folder on my project

Comment: My bad. You have to emit `/public`, as files contained in that directory are available from root. I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: Is it available at `http://localhost:WHATEVERYOURPORTIS/Programme robot/programme_palettisation_robot.tb`?

Comment: Yes it is, I can see it when I go to `http://localhost:WHATEVERYOURPORTIS/Programme robot/programme_palettisation_robot.tb` but I still have the same problem, when I download it, it says that the file cannot be found

Comment: In fact I saw it but now I can't see it anymore at this adress

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem (i think).
The file I wanted to download was a `.tb` which I think is not supported by VueJS. I put this file into a `.zip` folder and now it works.